# What does "${1/%\//}" expand to?

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
if [[ "$1" != "" ]]; then
    dr="${1/%\//}"
fi
```

In this above code, what does  `"${1/%\//}"` expand to?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's a roundabout way of removing a `/` at the end of the value of `$1` if it ends with a `/` in the `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh` shell.

It uses the non-standard `${parameter/%pattern/replacement}` parameter substitution, which replaces the text at the end of `$parameter` that matches `pattern`. The pattern used here is `\/`, i.e. a literal slash (it has to be escaped as it otherwise would act as a delimiter), and the replacement is empty. Thanks to the `if` test, the substitution and the assignment to `dr` is carried out only if the value `$1` is non-empty.

A more portable way of writing the same thing would be

```bsh
[ -n "$1" ] && dr=${1%/}
```

or,

```bsh
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    dr=${1%/}
fi
```

The standard substitution `${parameter%pattern}` removes (the shortest substring) what matches `pattern` from the end of the value in `$parameter`. In the code above I'm using this with the pattern `/` to remove the last character in the string if it is a slash.

The test is also changed to the less complicated `-n` test, which is *true* if the given string is non-empty.